# AngularJS Modyfing json with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I’ve got a simple JSON, for example:

```
{
  "Object 0": {}
}
```

And I want to display it as a tree. 
To do it, I am using something like this

```
<span>{{key}}</span> // Object 0
<span>{{value}}</span> // {}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-include="'views/itemList.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Howether I want be able to change either key’s name and it's value, so I add

```
<input ng-model=”items[key]”>
```

Inside my template, but its not working as it should. I am unable to change it’s content, since once i change it its not object anymore
I also dont know how to change key’s name from Object 0 to anything else without creating new item. Any Ideas?

There is another case
I've got.

```
$scope.test = {"test": "test1"}
```

And I want to be able to put this $scope.test into my "Object 0" so that it produce

```
{
  "Object 0": {
    "test": "test1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

For your second requirement you can simply do this

```
$scope.test = {"test": "test1"}
$scope.items = {
  "Object 0": $scope.test
}
```

It will give you

```
object {
  Object 0 : Object{
                    test:"test1"
                   }
       }
```

You can not change the key from veiw, Actually when you set a object with key in ng-model it assign that element the value of that key. Same thing it does from view to controller. If you change the value of this element from view, it will update the value for object on the key assign to the model.

Comment: I dont want to hardcode it, because this "simple" json can be just a regular json with 100 values, it's important to do it dynamically. For example I got ng-click="pasteValue()" and it should dynamically add value from $scope.copiedValue